# SQL Server - how can I get a string that starts with specific characters

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a string starts with `@` from full text.

My text is:

```
" Hello this is @jancooth from paradise"
```

I only want to get the `@jancooth` part.

Comment: Split the string into "words" using `' '` as a delimiter, and then it's trivial.

Comment: @Larnu do you have a script for this ?

Comment: There are literally 1,000's of examples already on [so] showing you how to split a string based on a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

`CHARINDEX` with `SUBSTRINGs` will work for you, assuming there is only one instance of `@`.

```
declare @testtext NVARCHAR(50) = 'Hello this is @jancooth from paradise'

select substring(@testtext,charindex('@',@testtext), charindex(' ',@testtext,charindex('@',@testtext)) - charindex('@',@testtext))
```

Comment: Glad I could help.